# Cross-compiling Go on Windows 64 (TDM-GCC-64) to .linux file, but keeps compiling to .exe file despite GOOS=linux

Tags: go, cross-compiling

I am attempting to compile a .go source file to a .linux file. I'm using TDM-GCC-64 on Windows 7 64-bit.

I have set my GOOS to 'linux'. I've also set GOARCH to amd64.

I then rebuild Go in C:\Go\src using make.bat. This all runs successfully.

The compilation runs successfully but each time it compiles a Windows .exe despite the system variables set.

My question is how to overcome this issue - what am I doing wrong?

Edit: I had MinGW installed before TDM-GCC, which did not work.

Comment: Are you sure your `GOOS` and `GOARCH` variables are *exported* and hence are seen by the processes being run?

Comment: If using GCC is not a strong requirement, I suggest to look at those two simpler approaches: https://github.com/mitchellh/gox and http://dave.cheney.net/2013/07/09/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go-1-1

Comment: Thanks kostix - I added them manually to the System Variables via Advanced Settings in the Win7 GUI, rather than from the command line. How do I know if they are exported?

Comment: Kluyg, I tried your first suggestion: [gox](http://github.com/mitchellh/gox) and this worked, but not straight off. It required I rebuilt Go (to create the toolchain?) and this threw an error of requiring gcc, so I reinstalled TDM-GCC, and it did work. Nothing had worked, and this works a treat for cross-compiling, so thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You can test to see if those values are exporting using echo like this:`echo %GOOS%`

If you modify the system variables without restarting your console it won't have the new values. You should try exporting via the command line using `set GOOS="linux"` and `set GOARCH="amd64"`

If this does not fix it I would follow the guide that Kluyg posted.

Comment: Thansk Ben, I used kluyg's suggestions first off and this worked using [gox](http://github.com/mitchellh/gox), although I had to recompile Go and so did need TDM-GCC, otherwise the compile failed.